# Generate documentation for custom implementation of Restful webservices

Tags: rest, swagger, restful-architecture, wadl, ibm-api-management

My project has a **custom implementation of Rest** for our API's (some 6k odd services) - We do not follow the **JAX-RS** specification.

I am looking for a way to **generate** a **Swagger (Yaml) document or WADL documentation** for these services so that we can list our API's on an API management platform.

Is there a way i could achieve this or any tool I could use to generate these automatically for me? 
I have come across some maven plugin's, but these either are for Frameworks implementing the JAX-RS specification or I need to manually annotate my classes with Swagger annotations.

Any help/pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so with a little initial pointers from the swagger community, we were able to achieve this.

We had an already implemented custom reader for our Rest API's. We modified this reader to generate swagger JSON files and wala - We had our desired output.